# How to set required to a custom select option?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show message required when user don't set a choice.

This is my code:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.myOptions');
var selecText = document.querySelector('.selectFeld>p');
var mylist = document.querySelector('.list_contrat');
//var iconSelect = document.querySelector(".icon_typeCont_rota");
var valueTypeContra = document.querySelector('#typecontrat');


for(option of options) {
    option.onclick = function() {
        mylist.classList.toggle('myhide');
        //iconSelect.classList.toggle('myRotate');
        selecText.innerHTML = this.textContent;
        valueTypeContra.value = this.getAttribute('data-value'); // get value select option
        
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="selectFeld" title="Type de contrat">
    <input type="text" name="typeContrat" id="typecontrat" class="d-none" required>
    <p>Type de contrat</p>
    <img src="icon_form/Icon_contrat_deroulant.png" alt="" class="icon_select">
</div>
<ul class="container-optionSelec list_contrat myhide">
    <li class="myOptions" data-value="redaction"><p>Redaction</p></li>
    <li class="myOptions" data-value="assistance"><p>Assistance</p></li>
</ul>
```

It's a custom select option, the code set the value for the input displayed none

Comment: What code do you have to make this a selectable element?

Comment: I use data-value to give value for the input

Comment: Do you have Javascript code to capture the `data-value` value? If so, include that.

Comment: I'v modified it

Comment: I wrapped your HTML in a `form` tag with a submit button and the `required` attribute on the text input field worked just fine. Are you trying something different?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, 
It work fine if the input is not displayed none but I've hide the input and set a custom field in selectFeld class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using a standard form element you're not able to use the standard `required` attribute, and therefore don't have the standard help features that goes along with it. And adding `required` to your input field does not present the built-in help message because you are hiding it.

You need to use Javascript to program a custom "required" message to go along with your custom form input mechanism. Naturally there are a number of ways to accomplish this, and present an error message to your user. What do you suppose works best for your users?

---

*Upon first glance...*

Remove the ineffective `required` attribute from the input element. Change the input to a `hidden` type, to avoid using css to hide it. And add a note to the instructions letting your users know ahead of time the selection is necessary to proceed.

Add a submit event handler to the form to capture submission and have an opportunity to validate the form. In the handler check the (now `hidden`) input field for an empty string indicating the custom selection mechanism has not been used. If the input value is empty, emphasize the instructions, and provide the user an error message.

For example:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.myOptions');
var selecText = document.querySelector('.selectFeld>p');
var mylist = document.querySelector('.list_contrat');
var valueTypeContra = document.querySelector('#typecontrat');

for (option of options) {
  option.onclick = function() {
    selecText.style.color = 'black'; // restore black color to instruction
    selecText.innerHTML = this.textContent;
    valueTypeContra.value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
  }
}

// GET FORM AND ADD SUBMIT EVENT HANDLER

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function () {

  // check if "typeContrat" is equal to an empty string
  if ( "" === this.elements['typeContrat'].value ) {
  
    // emphasize the instruction label
    selecText.style.color = 'red';
    // provide the user and alert message
    alert('Veuillez sélectionner type de contrat');
    // prevent the form from being submitted
    return false;
  }
  
  // if "typeContrat" is not an empty string submit the form
  else { return true; }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="selectFeld" title="Type de contrat">
    <input type="hidden" name="typeContrat" id="typecontrat" class="d-none" value="">
    <p>Type de contrat (required)</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="container-optionSelec list_contrat myhide">
    <li class="myOptions" data-value="redaction">
      <p>Redaction</p>
    </li>
    <li class="myOptions" data-value="assistance">
      <p>Assistance</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

*However,* there are many user interface approaches and programming mechanisms to accomplish this, so first determine what works best for your users, supports your application purpose, goals, and look, meets your security needs—and do that.